# How to limit number of HTTP Connections for a rest web service

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, connection-timeout, rate-limiting, httpconnection

We want to limit the number of connections for our rest web service.

We are using spring boot with jetty as server.

We have configured below settings :

```
#rate limit connections
server.jetty.acceptors=1
server.jetty.selectors=1

#connection time out in milliseconds
server.connection-timeout=-1
```

Now, as you can see that there is no idle timeout applicable for connections.
Which means a connection once open will remain active until it is explicitly closed.

So, with this settings, my understanding is that if I open more then 1 connection, then I should not get any response because the connection limit is only 1.

But this does not seem to be working. Response is sent to each request.

I am sending request with 3 different clients. I have verified the ip address and ports. They all are different for 3 clients. But all 3 remains active once connection is established.

Any experts to guide on the same?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the acceptors and selectors to 1 will not limit the max number of connections.

I suggest you look at using either the jetty [QoS filter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html), or the [Connection Limit](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-connectors.html#_limiting_connections) jetty module.